# SFMC journey engagement split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

if I want anyone click the first invite email and they will receive confirmation email in 10min. For the people that didn't click and they will receive 2nd invite email on 17 Nov. Is this the right way to do?

[image: journey]

Comment: I will recommend you use longer wait steps before your engagement split. It is very few opens that happen within the first 10 minutes after your email is sent. My recommendation will be 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can try is using for a confirmation email top be sent immediately after the link is clicked is making that link a cloudpage or code resource that runs some AMPscript to trigger the confirmation email.